# How to bind OpenCV-contribute-modules to MATLAB?

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, mex, opencv3.0

I want to use OpenCV class(from contribute_modules) in MATLAB. I am trying to perform binding of OpenCV to MATLAB. It is ok when I use standard opencv interface. But I need to use a class `xphoto` from contribute modules. I have already built OpenCV with contribute-modules in CMake & Visual Studio 2010. It is working fine. I checked use MATLAB. MATLAB paths were found well.
I followed a tutorial  from Github.

I still have this error in MATLAB:

`Building with 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2010'.
Error using mexOpenCV (line 120)
bm3d.cpp
C:\Users\Desktop\bm3d\bm3d.cpp(11) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'opencv2/xphoto.hpp': No such file or directory`

Could anyone help me please how I can do it ?

I would appreciate any help please.

Answer (score 0):

I'm several months late, but I'll answer here for posterity. mexOpenCV allows for `-I` , `-l` and `-L` flags, like what gcc allows. So, all you really need to do is to point to the libraries that you need in your CPP file using these flags. For example,

```
mexOpenCV getaruco.cpp -L~/opencv310/lib/ -lopencv_aruco.3.1.0 -I/usr/local/include
```

will link against the aruco module that lives in ~/opencv310/lib and the corresponding header is in /usr/local/include. I'm sure there are equivalent flags on Windows as well.

See `help mexOpenCV` in MATLAB for more details.